# How to speed up integrated folium map in streamlit

Tags: python, caching, folium, streamlit

I am creating a folium map using streamlit_folium module with streamit selectbox and radios to change the map based on the user choices but it loads to slowly. how can I speed it up.

Comment: Hi @Mahfoud B., can you add your code? So that people can run it themselves and fix what needs to be fixed. Without it, it's harder (if not impossible).

Comment: Sorry I can not put my code here. But I can tell you that I have fixed this issue by using @st.cache() for operations and data loading and by using geometry.simplify() when using folium